# Ordered lists shifted to the left when altering the display property

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, html-lists

```js
// If checked, set display to 'initial' otherwise set it to 'none'.

function check(event) {
  let ol = document.getElementById('list');
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    ol.style.display = 'initial';
  } else {
    ol.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

show.addEventListener('click', check, false);
```

```css
ol    {display: none;}
label {user-select: none;}
```

```html
<input id="show" type="checkbox" />
<label for="show">Show list</label>

<ol id="list">
  <li>list</li>
</ol>
```

The list is shifted to the left as seen, there is some part of that sticking out. Why does this happen? How to stop it? I packed the list up in a flex container but they appear to be shifted to the right:

```js
function check(event) {
  let ol = document.getElementById('list');
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    ol.style.display = 'initial';
  } else {
    ol.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

show.addEventListener('click', check, false);
```

```css
ol {
  display: none;
}

label {
  user-select: none;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}
```

```html
<input id="show" type="checkbox" />
<label for="show">Show List 1</label>

<div>
  <ol id="list">
    <li>list 1</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you want the bullet in front of your list item?

Comment: @TusharShahi No, I want them to be displayed as normal lists, not shifted to the left or right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css:

```
ol    {display: none;
list-style-type: none;}
label {user-select: none;}
input {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

The input has some `padding` and `margin`. I have removed it. Also, removed the styling from list using `list-style-type`. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/wvdwaXm)

Comment: But then how does the padding of `input` affect the list?

Comment: Correct, It does not. In fact, because of the padding the input looks a little on the right. I removed it so they align. The list is not shifted to the right, the input is shifted to the left.